# How to combine traditional and Future-based API in one interface in Dart?

Tags: dart, future, dart-async

I would like to parse binary file (from some old game) as on desktop as in browser.
So, I should use abstract class, which can read binary data from array of bytes:

```dart
abstract class BinData {

  int readByte();

  String readNullString(){
    var buffer = new StringBuffer();
    int char;

    do {
      char = readByte();
      if (char == 0){
        break;
      }
      buffer.writeCharCode(char);
    } while(true);

    return buffer.toString();
  }

}
```

Now I can implement my parser. For example:

```dart
class Parser {
  BinData _data;

  void load(BinData data){
     ...
  }
}
```

For desktop console application I use dart:io RandomAccessFile:

```dart
class FileBinData extends BinData {
  RandomAccessFile _file;

  FileBinData.from(RandomAccessFile file){
    this._file = file;
  }

  int readByte(){
    return this._file.readByteSync();
  }
}
```

For web application I have to use dart:html FileReader. However, this class has only Future-based API, which isn't compatible with my interface:

```dart
class WebFileBinData extends BinData {
  File _file;
  int _position = 0;

  WebFileBinData.from(File file){
    this._file = file;
  }

  int readByte(){
    Blob blob = _file.slice(_position, _position + 1); 

    FileReader reader = new FileReader();

    var future = reader.onLoad.map((e)=>reader.result).first
        .then((e) { ... });
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);

    ...
  }  
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you please point out what causes you troubles? Do you get any error? If the question is, can I continue synchronuous after an async call, then the answer is simple "no".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `readByte()` should return `Future<int>` instead of `int`. You can return a `Future` from a function/method even when it doesn't do any async operation (`return new Future.value(5);`) but you can not return `int` (or any non-Future value) from a function which executes async operations, at least not when the value should be returned as result of the async operation.

You also need to ensure to connect all async calls.

```dart
Future<int> readByte(){
  return reader.onLoad.map((e)=>reader.result).first
    .then((e) { 
      ... 
      return reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    });
```

** readNullString

```dart
  Future<String> readNullString() {
    var buffer = new StringBuffer();
    int char;

    return Future.doWhile(() {
      return readByte().then((char) {
        if (char == 0) {
          return false; // end doWhile
        }
        buffer.writeCharCode(char);
        return true; // continue doWhile
      });
    }).then((_) => buffer.toString()); // return function result 
  }
```

Comment: If a call goes async, there is no way back. This might look frightening at first but the earlier you get used to it the better. There is no way to avoid it in Dart. `async/await` makes it easier to use but it's still async. If you have more questions just create new questions and I'll try to help. I'll have a look at `readNullString()`

Comment: I see. I am OK to use async/await. The concept is understandable. If you or some one could show me how to implement the `readNullString()' using Futures my problem would be solved. Thanks in advance.